# How to get null object when user detail is not found using postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

currently I use this code.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(user_data) AS contact_info
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object('user_id', u._id, 
                            'name', u.name, 
                            'mobile', u.mobile, 
                            'profile', CASE WHEN u.profile IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT ('${process.env.S3_URL}', '', u.profile) ELSE NULL END, 
                            'address_list', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('_id', ua._id, 
                                                                         'address', address, 
                                                                         'lat', lat, 
                                                                         'long', long) 
                             ORDER BY user_id ASC)) AS user_data
  FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN users_address ua ON ua.user_id = u._id
  WHERE ua.user_id = ${contact_id}
    AND ua.is_deleted = 0
  GROUP BY u._id,
           u.name,
           u.mobile,
           u.profile
) t
```

Here i use two table > 1. users 2.users_address.   contact_id is nothing but a user id which store in users table. and in users_address i also stored a user_id for referrece so i can easily join that both table using user_id.

**current output**:

```
"data": {
        "name": "abhi",
        "mobile": "3256417890",
        "profile": "asda",
        "user_id": 1,
        "address_list": [
            {
                "_id": 3,
                "lat": 23.0031403,
                "long": 72.5337234,
                "address": "India"
            },
            {
                "_id": 5,
                "lat": 23.0031403,
                "long": 72.5337234,
                "address": "India"
            },
            {
                "_id": 7,
                "lat": 23.0031403,
                "long": 72.5337234,
                "address": "India"
            }
        ]
    }
```

this output is right but whenever i enter contact_id which having null data in users_address table then it throw error.

**if no data found then my expected output is :**

```
"data": {
        "name": "abhi",
        "mobile": "3256417890",
        "profile": "asda",
        "user_id": 1,
        "address_list": []
    }
```

please someone help me to figure out this error. Thank you in adavance.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a left join on users_address, you should put all related conditions on the users_address table **within** the LEFT JOIN conditions, instead of in a WHERE:

> ```
>     LEFT JOIN users_address ua ON ua.user_id = u._id
>   WHERE ua.user_id = ${contact_id}
>     AND ua.is_deleted = 0
> ```

Should be

```
    LEFT JOIN users_address ua ON (ua.user_id = u._id
  AND ua.user_id = ${contact_id}
    AND ua.is_deleted = 0)
```

The difference is that the WHERE will apply the conditions on the null cells returned by the LEFT JOIN, so it will remove them.

Also, you don't need the clause

> `WHERE ua.user_id = ${contact_id}`

This is covered by your LEFT JOIN clause already (and it is dangerous to pass raw variables to your SQL string)